Testnet USDC from https://staging.aave.com/faucet/ not showing on Metamask
I am getting Testnet USDC from https://staging.aave.com/faucet/ not showing on Metamask
I approved the Transaction in Metamask.
It is showing on Aave page at USDC Testnet Faucet but not showing on Metamask.
I require to send USDC from Metamask to my Smartcontract
thanks
Uday

Make sure you're attempting to claim the Testnet USDC on the correct network which in this case is Ethereum Testnet (Sepolia).
In the top left corner of the Metamask extension, you can switch Networks.
You can use any of the Sepolia RPC Node endpoints listed below:

https://rpc.sepolia.dev
https://rpc.sepolia.org/
https://rpc2.sepolia.org/
https://rpc.sepolia.online/


I had selected Sepolia from the list of Testnets in Metamask. I had not given any RPC ID etc.

results of SEPOLIA ETHERSCAN
Transaction Hash:
0x2aa782b2acb0c24d0e9ca2a5b72c0b1fe25686b31031ca3c953319f3821570fb
0xD62f1B97...3cEe3D67f
on
0xC959483D...EDEb3f42D
From:
0xD62f1B978D60a91e34AB133DF68b33B3cEe3D67f
Interacted With (To):
0xC959483DBa39aa9E78757139af0e9a2EDEb3f42D
ERC-20 Tokens Transferred:
0x00000000...000000000
To
0xD62f1B97...3cEe3D67f
For
10,000
USDC
(USDC)
Value:
0 ETH
($0.00)
Transaction Fee:
0.001117175946134094 ETH
($0.00)
Gas Price:
24.444258498 Gwei (0.000000024444258498 ETH)

If you're currently on the Sepolia Testnet Network with the correct wallet connected and you still don't see your USDC Testnet tokens, then you need to import them manually within Metamask.
Go to Metamask => Click "Import Tokens" at the bottom of your wallet => Click on the "Custom Token" tab => Paste the USDC Token address in the required field.
In this instance, I've got the token address to hand for you for convenience: 0x94a9D9AC8a22534E3FaCa9F4e7F2E2cf85d5E4C8
